# How to replace PDF field value by Image using iText7 in .NETCore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, itext7

I've implemented it in iTextSharp but now i want to convert into iText7.

```
 var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfPath1);
 string outputfile = string.Empty;
 var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
 var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
 outputfile = string.Empty;

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sign1))
    {
        PushbuttonField pushbuttonField = pdfFormFields.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("imgSign1");
        pushbuttonField.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;
        pushbuttonField.ProportionalIcon = true;
        pushbuttonField.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(sign1);
        pdfFormFields.ReplacePushbuttonField("imgSign1", pushbuttonField.Field);
    }
```

i've tried to convert it but not getting  proper way

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfPath1);
 var fstream = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create);
 var pdfwriter = new PdfWriter(fstream);
 var document = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfwriter);
 var acroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(document, true);

 outputfile = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sign1))
            {
                //what will be the alternative for PushbuttonField in iText7.
               
            }
```